# Bounce A Ball of off a Circle

Tags: geometry, bounce

So I am making a game that's like slime volleyball. Basically, my two main players, or objects, are half circles on either side, I have a net in the middle, and a ball.  My problem is I can't figure out how to make the ball bounce of a semi circle so that it follows both the angle and direction. I've tried looking it up, but all of them are either about walls or rectangles, not bouncing off a circular object. Any code or ideas would help.

Comment: Can you provide some code, based on that, it would be easier to try and help you. Also in what language are you programming?

Comment: look into box2d. it's available for most languages you would be asking stack overflow about

Comment: This is really more of a math/physics question.  Have you tried implementing the physics in code yet?

Comment: can you draw a tangent to the circle at the point of bounce? you can then treat that tangent as your "wall" and bounce. But it's really a math problem, not a programming problem. Or, physics, if your wall has any worldly attributes.

Comment: im using java, sry about that, but yea. i think i have the math somewhat figured out now thanks! ...ill try to upload the code tonight to show where i am at right now...

Answer (score 1):

"Take a semicircle, point it upwards, shine parallel rays of light straight down at it, and let those rays reflect off it. The envelope of the reflected rays will be half of a [nephroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephroid)":

---

[image: ParallelRaysCirc]

          

<sup>Image source: [John Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/rolling/rolling_2.html).</sup>

---

More directly, assume you have a ray *r* along your ball path.
Find the intersection point *p* of *r* with your semicircle *C*.
Compute the tangent *t* at *p*.
Compute the normal *n* at *p*.
Reflect *r* over *n* to *r'*.

Comment: This is correct, but I'm not sure why you're mentioning nephroids. Also, note that it's not physically accurate with balls (where rotation is an important dynamic).

Comment: @Veedrac: I mentioned nephroids to explain the image.